# ExpandableHeightListView ImageView Item layout_height wrap_content not showing all image

Tags: android, android-studio

anyone can help me. i have **ExpandableHeightListView**

```
<com.example.administrator.mosbeau.ExpandableHeightListView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/paymentlist"
android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
android:dividerHeight="10dp"
android:layout_below="@+id/shortdesc"/>
```

with **ImageView Item** layout_height wrap_content

```
<ImageView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/payment_icon"
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
android:scaleType="fitStart"
android:layout_below="@+id/borderfooter"/>
```

images have different height that's why i set wrap_content.

but the problem is not showing all image

**class**

```
paymentadapter = new ListViewAdapterPayment(getActivity(), paymentarraylist, listener);
paymentlistview.setAdapter(paymentadapter);
paymentlistview.setExpanded(true);
```

**adapter**

```
payment_icon = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.payment_icon);
Glide.with(context).load(resultp.get(CheckoutFragment2.payment_icon)).apply(requestOptions).into(payment_icon);
```

when i set height to ImageView like layout_height="100dp", it show all the content.

anyone can help me with this problem. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

u should set imageView's height in you code

```
Glide.with(context).load(imgUrl).placeholder(R.mipmap.place_holder)
            .error(R.mipmap.place_holder).into(object : SimpleTarget<Drawable>(){
            override fun onResourceReady(resource: Drawable, transition: Transition<in Drawable>?) {
                var params =  payment_icon.layoutParams
                params.height = resource.intrinsicHeight
                imageView.layoutParams = params
                payment_icon.setImageDrawable(resource)
                }
        })
```